# difference between symposium and workshop?

Tags: conference, workshop

I am not sure if it is too naive, but can anyone please let me know the difference between a symposium and a workshop.

I aim to submit my paper to a conference where call-for-paper is for the symposium and workshop both. I cannot understand where I should submit this paper.

Where are the chances of getting submission more? and what are the criteria in both?

Comment: There are two questions on our site. (1) [Is there a difference between a symposium paper and a conference paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87745/546) (2) [What is the difference between a conference paper and a workshop paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/96127/546). Do they answer your question?

Comment: Forgot to mention, when you read the second question I linked above, there is another question linked to it that may be helpful: [What is the point in publishing a paper in a workshop rather than in a conference?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/86220/546)

Comment: One of them is spelled with a Y, and the other is spelled with a W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your description it seems like the main or the principal track(s) of the conference are the symposium(s) and that the workshops are sided events. So, typically, workshops are smaller, more focused on a given subject or theme within a larger research field. The symposium is, typically, wider with several subjects being contemplated within a research field. For example, a conference in Software Engineering (wider) can have a workshop on Model-driven Software Engineering (specific).

So, usually, it is more *easier* to be accepted in a workshop, if and only if, your contribution is really focused on the subject of it. For the main track, it is typically more complicated because there should be clear contributions to the state of art in an area of study, with well-stated results and more detailed *research*.

Comment: So, if my paper is unable to get through to the symposium, can the editors direct it to any of the workshops?

Comment: That depends on the conference, but usually, you manually re-submit to the workshop in case of rejection. As conference organizers are aware of this, the workshop deadline is (most of the time) after the notification date.

Comment: In my case, the wkshp deadline is just 1 day b4 the symp. result announcement i.e. the wkshp submission deadline is 14th July and the symp. result will come on 15th. Actually, when I submitted, there was no mention of wkshp. There was only wkshp proposal and my supervisor thought that the wkshp proposals would go on till the final dates and told me to submit in open categories. Frankly, now I am worried as I have heard that rejection rate in symp is high and this is a v. good conf. in our field (IEEE GLOBECOM 2018) and I want to be attend this conf and have my paper there for sure :(